# rmarkdown::render vs Source()

Tags: r, r-markdown

I have two .RMD documents; one with general data manipulation and tidying, and another with visualisations.

I was looking to run the tidying document at the begging of visualisations files to ensure I'm using my most up-to-date data.

my intial thought was to use  `source()` however `source("Data tidying.Rmd")` gives me the error,
**"Error in source("Data tidying.Rmd") : attempt to use zero-length variable name"**

I couldn't work out what would cause this, because the document it self runs fine ? is it trying to run content, not in code blocks as R ?

I couldn't get this to work, so i decided to use `rmarkdown::render` as an alternative
`rmarkdown::render("tidying.Rmd")` works great and does exactly what I want it to, until I want to Knitt my visualisation document. Instead i now have the problem of duplicate code blocks due to having

```
{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE,collapse=TRUE)
```

at the beginnin of my .RMD documents. I guess i could change my setup chunks to have no name, but ideally I'll like to be able to keep named blocks and run other RMD documents from inside the one I'm working with.

Comment: `source` parses your markdown file, but it cannot evaluate all those expressions because many of the expressions in a markdown file are not valid R code (for example `{r setup, include=FALSE}` is not valid R code). You need to use `render` to generate a markdown file. It looks like these are both things you figured out though. As to what is causing duplicate code blocks in your output, it is hard to say without a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example).

Comment: `source` will work on a `.R` file, not on an `.Rmd` file, since you cannot type `\`\`\`{r setup}` in an R console and expect the R parser to know what to do with it. The premise of the latter format is text-like stuff with some code snippets in clearly-defined code blocks/chunks. Similarly, one cannot run `source(.)` on python code (wrong programming language), `.docx` files (whether or not all of the text content is valid R code), or any other file that is not simply a text file where _everything_ is parse-able R expressions.

Comment: Thank you both for your input, helped contextualise what was going on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First use `knitr::purl()` to extract the source code, then `source()` it:

```r
knitr::purl("mydoc.Rmd")
source("mydoc.R")
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, solved my issue. I hadn't come across purl before, and it would have never occured to me to extract the R code to a new file and source that !